# How to enable events so Workbook_BeforeSave gets called

Tags: excel, vba

My `Workbook_BeforeSave` event is not called before saving

This is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
   a = MsgBox("Do you really want to save the workbook?", vbYesNo)
   If a = vbNo Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

This is probably normal, because events are probably not enabled.
Now I tried to put `Application.Events = True` like this:

```
Option Explicit
Application.Events = True

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
   a = MsgBox("Do you really want to save the workbook?", vbYesNo)
   If a = vbNo Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

This doesn't change anything, Workbook_BeforeSave is still not called up on saving. But when I close the excel file, following error message is displayed :

[image]

The english translation is "Compilation error: Incorrect instruction outside of a procedure."

Apparently the `Application.Events = True` is not at the right place, but where should I put it ?

Comment: the code between option explicit and the `Workbook_BeforeSave` subroutine does not run because its not called. I think you'll have to add an extra sub that you run through manually that enables events.

Comment: First it's `Application.EnableEvents = True`. Second, and more importantly, you need to figure out why events are disabled. ;)

Comment: @Goosebumbs : actually the problem is: how can I enable events automatically.

Comment: @Rory : thanks for pointing out that it's `Application.EnableEvents = True`. It seems events are disabled by default. Is there a way to enable events autoatically ?

Comment: Events *can't* be disabled by default - they have to be disabled in code. Are you sure you have macros enabled? If so, there must be code somewhere that is disabling events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope these will help:

1. `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)` must be inside `ThisWorkbook` in a VBA project.
2. `Application.EnableEvents = True` can not be inserted outside procedure or function.
3. Events are enabled by default. So, there must be somewhere inside vba project Events are getting disabled. This can be searched by :

   Once you are inside VBA project, Press Ctrl+F to open the Find dialog box. Then search for application.enableevents in the current project. Press Find Next. See the image below.
4. You can use a little sub to change and view the Application.EnableEvents status (ON/OFF). Place the sub under any standard module. See the image below.

[image]