# BeforeSave not functioning well in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a problem running a vba script using BeforeSave in Excel.
I am running this script, but I can save the file without any problems or Msgbox.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
a = MsgBox("Do you really want to save the workbook?", vbYesNo)
If a = vbNo Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

What is the problem?
It should show a Msgbox where I can cancel to save.

Comment: Are Events enabled?

Comment: I don't have any code to unable events.

Comment: I restarted excel and now it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Trust Center settings on File>options>Trust Center>Trust Center settings>Macro Settings. 
Check the radio button next to"enable all" and see what happens

and also, your file must have the extension of xlsb or xlsm

Comment: well, it works for me. There seems to be no problem with the code. there should be something else. can you also check the event status by writing "?application.EnableEvents" in immediate window

Answer (score 0):

`Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)` must be inside `ThisWorkbook` in a VBA project.

[image]

Comment: Yes it is inside ThisWorkbook

Comment: Maby this will help: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296597/how-to-enable-events-so-workbook-beforesave-gets-called)

Comment: No it didn't help. I tryied all the things in the post, but I can still save the document without a MsgBox